# Why is retrieving files from GitHub using R so slow all of the sudden on my computer?

Tags: r, github

So I have this shiny app which requires two files to be retrieved from GitHub in order for it to work properly, and up until today the download of these two files took at most 15-20 seconds. Today it just stays stuck without being able to download.
The files are the following:

```
#GET FILES FROM GITHUB
file_spb<-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tadeu95/BAGS/master/species_per_bin.txt"
spb<-read.delim(file_spb,quote = "",comment.char = "")
file_bps<-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tadeu95/BAGS/master/bin_per_species.txt"
bps<-read.delim(file_bps,quote = "",comment.char = "")
```

I checked my download speed on google and it was about 101 mb/s so I really don't know what's happening because the files aren't really that big.

Comment: Calling just the first file took 0.375s on my machine, and the second took 0.591s. It could have been a server error. You might also consider a number of packages that parse large text files faster, like `readr` or `data.table::fread`

Comment: yes I changed from read.delim to fread and suddenly it's very fast thanks for the suggestion